# *** glibc detected *** ./bst: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xbf91f3d8 *** C Programming

Tags: c

I'm working in C and it's giving me a hard time with pointers in my binary search tree. Everything compiles fine with no errors or warnings, but I get this error when I try to run it after entering the values:

```
Enter 5 integer values to place in tree:
5
1
4
6
2
Input values:
5
1
4
6
2
*** glibc detected *** ./bst: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xbfd6e988 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb763eee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x765c5)[0xb763f5c5]
./bst[0x80486f0]
./bst[0x80488c7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75e24d3]
./bst[0x80484b1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:1a 18031111       /home
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 00:1a 18031111       /home
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 00:1a 18031111       /home
08232000-08253000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b758c000-b75a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 22544428   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75a8000-b75a9000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 22544428   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75a9000-b75aa000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 22544428   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75c8000-b75c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75c9000-b776d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 22551295   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b776d000-b776f000 r--p 001a4000 08:01 22551295   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b776f000-b7770000 rw-p 001a6000 08:01 22551295   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7770000-b7773000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b778e000-b7793000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7793000-b7794000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7794000-b77b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 22551285   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77b4000-b77b5000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 22551285   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77b5000-b77b6000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 22551285   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bfd4e000-bfd6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my 
**bst.c**

```
/// Recursively traverses the tree and prints 
/// the value of each node.
/// @param root - a pointer to the root of the tree to traverse
/// @param type - the traversal type
void traverse(const TreeNode* root, const TraversalType type)
{
if( root == NULL ) return;

//PREORDER
if( type == 0 )
{
    printf( "%d\n", root->data );
    traverse( root->left, PREORDER );
    traverse( root->right, PREORDER );
}
//INORDER
else if( type == 1 )
{
    traverse( root->left, INORDER );
    printf( "%d\n", root->data );
    traverse( root->right, INORDER );
}
//POSTORDER
else if( type == 2 )
{
    traverse( root->left, POSTORDER );
    traverse( root->right, POSTORDER );
    printf( "%d\n", root->data );
}
}
/// Helper method of build_tree. Recursively adds the second
/// TreeNode to the passed root.
/// @param root - a pointer to the pointer to the root of the tree
///               to build this tree on to.
/// @param next - The TreeNode to be added to the Tree
static void addToTree( struct TreeNode** root, struct TreeNode* next)
{
if( (*root)->data >= next->data )
{
    if( (*root)->left == NULL )
    {
        (*root)->left = next;
    }
    else
    {
        addToTree( &(*root)->left, next );
    }
}
else
{
    if( (*root)->right == NULL )
    {
        (*root)->right = next;
    }
    else
    {
        addToTree( &(*root)->left, next );
    }
}
}
/// Dynamically build BST by allocating nodes on the heap
/// Note that the BST will support duplicate values by
/// placing them into the left child's subtree
/// @param root - a pointer to the pointer to the root of the tree
///               to build this tree on to.
/// @param elements - array of integers to add to the tree
/// @param count - the number of integers in the array
void build_tree(TreeNode** root, const int elements[], const int count)
{
struct TreeNode *new = (struct TreeNode*) malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ));
new->data = elements[0];
new->left = NULL;
new->right = NULL;
free( root );
*root = new;
int i;
for( i = 1; i < count; i++ )
{
    struct TreeNode next = {elements[i], NULL, NULL};
    addToTree( root, &next );
}
}
/// The main function presents the core features of the C language.
/// @param argc  number of command line arguments, including program name
/// @param argv  supplied command line arguments, including program name
/// @returns error_code  the error Code; 0 if no error
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if( argc != 2 )
{
    printf( "Usage: bst #\n" );
    return 1;
}
int numNodes = atoi( argv[1] );
if( numNodes <= 0 )
{
    printf( "# must be greater than 0\n" );
    return 1;
}

char buff[80];
int nodeVals[numNodes];
printf( "Enter %d integer values to place in tree:\n", numNodes );
int i;
for( i = 0; i < numNodes; i++ )
{
    if(fgets(buff, 80, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError reading Node Values.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeVals[i] = atoi( buff );
    }
}

printf( "Input values:\n" );
for( i = 0; i < numNodes; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d\n", nodeVals[i] );
}

TreeNode *root = malloc( sizeof( TreeNode ) );
build_tree( &root, nodeVals, numNodes);
printf( "Preorder:\n" );
traverse( root, PREORDER );
printf( "Inorder:\n" );
traverse( root, INORDER );
printf( "Postorder\n" );
traverse( root, POSTORDER );
return 0;
}
```

Here is my **bst.h**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

typedef struct TreeNode {
int data ;                  // the data stored in the node
struct TreeNode* left ;     // node's left child
struct TreeNode* right ;    // node's right child
} TreeNode;

typedef enum {
PREORDER,           // parent -> left -> right
INORDER,            // left -> parent -> right
POSTORDER           // left -> right -> parent
} TraversalType;

void build_tree(TreeNode** root, const int elements[], const int count);

void traverse(const TreeNode* root, const TraversalType type);

void cleanup_tree(TreeNode* root);

#endif
```

Here is some **sample output**

```
$ bst 7
Enter 7 integer values to place in tree:
6
1
42
3
24
18
5
Input values:
6
1
42
3
24
18
5
Preorder:
6
1
3
5
42
24
18
Inorder:
1
3
5
6
18
24
42
Postorder:
5
3
1
18
24
42
6
```

Could anyone help me please? And also maybe explain a little about pointers too.

Comment: Hey, could you please compile your code with debug information and post the resulting stack trace? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code has a problem:

```
for( i = 1; i < count; i++ )
{
    struct TreeNode next = {elements[i], NULL, NULL};
    addToTree( root, &next );
}
```

The `addToTree` function just puts the pointer you give it into the tree. However, this is a pointer to an object that ceases to exist at the end of the current loop iteration.

I suppose you want to dynamically allocate `next` each iteration, instead of using a local object.

(There may be other issues too, just this one stood out to me on a quick scan of the code).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel stupid. In the **addToTree** function, in the else statement:

```
else
{
    if( (*root)->right == NULL )
{
    (*root)->right = next;
}
else
{
    addToTree( &(*root)->left, next );
}
}
```

I called **addToTree( &(*root)->left, next );** which is supposed to add it to the tree in the right spot, but sends it to the left. Thus, it got stuck here. Basically a syntax error.

So it should be:

```
 addToTree( &(*root)->right, next );
```

That makes it functional, but there is still a lot of work before it is efficient in the memory sense.